# byte[] does not contain a definition for SequenceEqual authentication method

Tags: c#, linq, web-services, rest, authentication

Can anyone help with some problems I have. I am trying to create an self made authentication method, im abit stuck in a few areas and was hoping some one could help. First thing I would like to ask is how to solve the problem I have commented in the code:

```
    public string Authentication(string studentID, string password)
    {
        var result = students.FirstOrDefault(n => n.StudentID == studentID);
        //find the StudentID that matches the string studentID 
        if (result != null)
        //if result matches then do this
        {
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
            byte[] passwordHash = Hash(password, result.Salt);
            string HashedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(passwordHash);
            //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // take the specific students salt and generate hash/salt for string password (same way student.Passowrd was created)

            System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] UserPassword = enc.GetBytes(HashedPassword);
            UserPassword.SequenceEqual(result.Password); // byte[] does not contain a definition for SequenceEqual?
            //check if the HashedPassword (string password) matches the stored student.Password
        }
        return result.StudentID; 
        //if string password(HashedPassword)  matches stored hash(student.Passowrd) return student list 


        //else return a message saying login failed 
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Cannot be used like a method" is likely because you added brackets: `result.Password()` if it is a property drop the brackets `result.Password`. Adding the brackets makes the compiler attempt to compile it as a method call when in fact it is a property or field.

The second error is you are trying to return `students`, which is a list of students. The method requires a `string` as a return value. Did you mean to instead `return result.StudentID;`? The exception is detailing the failed attempt at compiling the cast from `List<Student>` to `string`.

I cannot offer any advice on the second half of your questions.

**Update**

You are expected to find a method called `SequenceEqual` on `byte[]`. This is a Linq extension method so you may need to add:

`using System.Linq;`

To the top of your file.

You will then likely get an error trying to pass a string to this method: `SequenceEqual(result.Password);`.

Comment: AHHH bingo on the return result.StudentID that solved that, if i drop the brackets tho the entire line is wrong

Comment: it says byte[] does not contain sequence equal? The second half I could probably figure out if I get the first bit working. Just wanted to show my thinking.

Comment: @JungleBoogie That sounds like the next error. I can't help with that. Create a new question with a sample demonstrating the issue.

Comment: No problem Adam I changed the code to reflect these changes (rather than creating a duplicate question) +1 for the help tho!

Comment: @JungleBoogie The `byte[]` type doesn't have a method called `SequenceEqual`. Is this a method you have created?

Comment: Yeah from the line above it `byte[] UserPassword = enc.GetBytes(HashedPassword);` I was told from a previous question this is how you do it but it had those problems to begin with all he said was try with ToArray or ToList and I did but it never worked...

Comment: Im trying to compare the string password after it is hashed/salted to the already hashed/salted Student.Password if they match then walla!

Comment: You aren't comparing apples to apples. I'm not sure what you are trying to do by converting a string to bytes, then back to a string, then back to bytes. To compare two strings (as in, 2 string representations of password hashes) you can simply do `hash1 == hash2`.

Comment: I'm bailing out of this question, it is ballooning into a debugging session and this isn't a good fit for this site.

Comment: True I will go have another thought on it maybe I can square away the question and accept your answer bud.